# set parameter when remapped (launch file)

Tags: ros, roslaunch, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I remapped the node name through launch file, also I set a parameter inside launch file. What happened is, the parameter is set on the original name of the node.
Heres my launch file:

```
 <launch>
     <node name ="original_node" pkg ="test_pkg" type ="original_node" output="screen">
     <remap from="/original_node" to="/new_node"/>
     <param name="number_string" type="string" value="123456" />
     </node>
 </launch>
```

Heres the rosparam list:

```
 /original_node/number_string
 /rosdistro
 /roslaunch/uris/host_public_virtualbox__41145
 /rosversion
 /run_id
```

Im expecting to have /new_node/number_string on my rosparam list. Any guide on how can I set my parameter based on the remapped node name inside launch file?

Note: I tried putting  under  but I explicitly typed the remapped node. This one works but is there any other method in which I only change the remap and not the param name?

```
 <launch>
     <node name ="original_node" pkg ="test_pkg" type ="original_node" output="screen">
     <remap from="/original_node" to="/new_node"/>
     </node>
     <param name="/new_node/number_string" type="string" value="123456" />
 </launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400954/set-parameter-when-remapped-(launch-file)/) by [naihart](https://answers.ros.org/users/100587/naihart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2022-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to try removing the `/` from the remaps, I know they can cause issues.

```
<remap from="original_node" to="new_node"/>
```

It also looks like your node of type `original_node` uses the `name` tag to add the namespace `original_node`. This means you could also do:

```
<node name ="new_node" pkg ="test_pkg" type ="original_node" output="screen">
```

And that might also work.

EDIT to respond to your comment:

If 1 already works, then 2 isn't adding anything. Which means the remap simply isn't working. Hence why 3 works.

As for your question about the difference between remap and renaming it: If you check `rosnode list` you will see that, by renaming, it should also show up as `new_node` while if remapped correctly it should still show up as `original_node`.

Remapping is only simply changing the name of the topic to whatever you like. This can be useful if (example) you're using a robot that has the default `cmd_vel` topic as `cmd_vel_unstamped` and you need your teleop to work with that. Then you can simply remap your teleop from `cmd_vel` to `cmd_vel_unstamped`. Changing the node *name* in this case would also not solve anything. Teleop would still publish to the wrong topic.

So they're two very different solutions to (in this specific case) the same result.

There is something that I am wondering: Can you even remap a portion of the topic, or a namespace like that?

Which makes me wonder, would you not need to do something like: `<remap from="original_node/number_string" to="new_node/123456"/>`. Remapping the entire topic and combining the remap and parameter in 1.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naihart](https://answers.ros.org/users/100587/naihart/) on 2022-05-20**:
These are the series of test that I have done.

1. renaming the node name same as the remap to - it works
2. with or without slashes on the remap as long as Ive done the number 1, everything works fine.
3. tried to delete remap, just rename the node name and this also works

now Im wondering, what is the difference of using remap on renaming the node name?

**Comment by [naihart](https://answers.ros.org/users/100587/naihart/) on 2022-05-21**:
Wow, thank you so much for explaining. I get it now. Cheers!